# onConfigurationChanged() is sometimes not calling when rotating faster

Tags: android, android-layout

This behavior is fond in Android GingerBread. I had override the onConfigurationChanged() to update the layout on changing the orientation of my device.(updated android:configChanges attribute in manifest file.) Also registered an onOrientationChanged() callback in the application.  When I change the orientation from one to another it's getting call back for both config and orientation change.(which is the expected one)

But when I follow the below step, sometimes its not getting my layout updated(getting some black screen)

- Rotate the devices continuously through all the 4 orientation
- Do not give enough time to redraw the layout at each orientation
- stop in some orientation after some rotations

When I traced the logs, I can find out that for all orientation change                     onOrientationChanged() is called. But onConfigurationChanged() is calling only for some cases. The black screen is getting when onConfigurationChanged() is not called(I am using setContentView() in side this call back)

Can any one tell me what will be the cause for this. Or give me direction to where should I look to trace this. Like from method onConfigurationChanged() is called.

The application is working fine in froyo.

Advanced thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem.
If quickly rotate the device 180 degrees, then onConfigurationChanged() is not called.
Also, if you remove the android:configChanges = "orientation" and rapidly rotate, then do not call onCreate().

Log, slow rotation:

```
01-14 03:03:23.401: D/WindowManager(27840): [rotationForOrientationLw] return curRotation: curRotation 0
01-14 03:03:23.401: I/WindowManager(27840): Setting rotation to 0, animFlags=0
01-14 03:03:23.401: I/ActivityManager(27840): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=257/4 loc=ru_RU touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=2 layout=35 uiMode=17 seq=1163}
01-14 03:03:23.411: D/TestActivity(30737): onConfigurationChanged  
01-14 03:03:23.411: D/TestActivity(30737): getRotation:newOrientation = 0
01-14 03:03:23.431: D/PinyinIME(27909): onStartInput  ccontentType: 0 Restarting:true
01-14 03:03:23.451: W/com.skype.raider.MainApp(28091): onConfigurationChanged changed:{ scale=1.0 imsi=257/4 loc=ru_RU touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=2 layout=35 uiMode=17 seq=1163}
01-14 03:03:23.501: I/MyEvent(28098): onReceive:Action=android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
01-14 03:03:23.501: I/MyEvent(28098): updateUI
01-14 03:03:23.501: I/MyEvent(28098): updateUI,len=1
01-14 03:03:23.511: I/MyEvent(28098): MyEventAppWidgetProvider onUpdate
01-14 03:03:23.511: I/MyEvent(28098): MyEventAppWidgetProvider onUpdate: for=0
01-14 03:03:23.511: I/MyEvent(28098): widgetid=7
01-14 03:03:23.531: E/MyEvent(28098): MyEventAppWidgetService onStart
01-14 03:03:23.701: D/Chi-TRACE(27840): ________current Screen is ORIENTATION_2
01-14 03:03:23.871: D/CChi(27840): ________pause = false
01-14 03:03:24.301: D/skia(30737): purging 195K from font cache [28 entries]
```

Log, fast rotation:

```
01-14 03:03:55.314: D/WindowManager(27840): [rotationForOrientationLw] return curRotation: curRotation 3
01-14 03:03:55.314: I/WindowManager(27840): Setting rotation to 3, animFlags=0
```

We can see that the system sees the rotation, but does not says about this no one. Why?
How do I fix it?

HuaweyS7, Android 2.2.2.

**UPD**

I found answer:
"but landscape is landscape, regardless if it's 180 degrees,
so the system may not consider it to be a configuration change." 
[full discussion here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/219676c074b1a558#)

**ALSO**
From Android sources:

Accelerometer listener com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.MyOrientationListener.onOrientationChanged() - pay attention to second parameter in function call, it named alwaysSendConfiguration:

```
mWindowManager.setRotation(rotation, false, mFancyRotationAnimation);
```

setRotation() calls:

```
setRotationUnchecked(rotation, alwaysSendConfiguration, animFlags);
```

And, finally, in setRotationUnchecked:

```
synchronized(mWindowMap) {
        changed = setRotationUncheckedLocked(rotation, animFlags);
    }
    if (changed || alwaysSendConfiguration) {
        sendNewConfiguration();
    }
```

Where in sendNewConfiguration() calls ActivityManager, and it calls only if configuration changed or if alwaysSendConfiguration set to true.

Answer (score -1):

it is not called only if previous function wasn't finished yet, because it's not collecting calls in the stack.